# Manga where a boy attempts to fight an evil god, he can communicate with a girl who is a sword and can use "God's Paw"

Tags: story-identification, manga

All I can remember is that the manga opens up with a boy who is able to communicate with a girl that is a sword. Also when he is fighting he uses something called God's Paw and it leaves a handprint in the sky. And last, I remember he attempts to fight "god", who isn’t very godly and is evil. When he tries to fight god he fails, and he and his friends end up being separated but somehow meet up way farther in the future.

Comment: Please don't edit your post to say you've found it and remove all other content. Instead you can answer your own question and state what the manga is that you've found!

Comment: Yes, please let us know the manga! I'm curious.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about *[Keizoku wa Maryoku nari: Hazure Mahou de Isekai Musou](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/keizoku-wa-maryoku-nari-hazure-mahou-de-isekai-musou)*.

[image: Front cover of Keizoku wa Maryoku nari: Hazure Mahou de Isekai Musou]

> After diligently trained his magic every day, one day Leons found out that his specialty magic, Creation Magic, is trash! However, with his unbelievable amount of mana and amazingly good luck, Leons is able to turn that useless magic into a method to create various things, like a super masochist magic sword that can speak for example! Moreover, he also got closer to Princess Sheria and the grand daughter of the Holy Maiden, Riana, after he presented his creation to them!

In this the mc can talk to a sword girl but I haven't read it much so I am not sure.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Since it is a major distinct factor in the question, can you at least confirm the existence of a power called "God's Paw" or something similar?  Any other lines or frames you could quote to establish the "girl that is a sword" or any other elements from the question would also help a lot.

Comment: As of Chapter 7 (the latest I could find translated), there is not "God's Paw".